# Resource ID #0x0 in AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, resources, android-alertdialog

I adding an `AlertDialog` in kotlin file, but get exception

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener { view ->
            login()
        }


fun login() {

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@LoginActivity)
        builder.setView(R.layout.layout_loading_dialog)
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
     }
```

**Exception**

```
   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2133)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1142)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
```

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="20dp">
    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Please wait! This may take a moment." />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u share your layout `layout_loading_dialog.XML` file with question

Comment: @NileshRathod posted.

Comment: R u share you are getting exception from above code because code looks fine for me

Comment: @NileshRathod yes,and it crashed on this line `dialog.show()`

Comment: @NileshRathod I have solved it.Thanks

Comment: Happy to here that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine after I modified to below code.

```
var dialogs = Dialog(this)
dialogs.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
dialogs.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
dialogs.setCancelable(false)
dialogs.setContentView(R.layout.layout_loading_dialog)
dialogs.show()
```

No idea why.

Comment: You Just  replaced `AlertDialog.Builder` with `Dialog`

Answer (score 1):

> Above error comes if your application doesn't find out the resource.

It have alot of possibilities. Such as sometimes we store files `style-v21` , `values-v21` or more.

**Note:-** Just check your `layout_loading_dialog.xml` inside the `layout` folder. It should not be inside the `layout-v21` folder.

[image]

It above picture `fragment_sign_up_and_login.xml` is inside your `layout` folder but `fragment_splash.xml` is inside the `layout-v21` folder.

Comment: I checked, it inside `layout` folder.

Comment: you code looks fine. Have you used another resource inside your application ?