# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException when loading activity

Tags: java, android, xml

At the start of my app a splash activity should be displayed, but when loading a certain drawable located in "src/drawabe/background_splash.xml" I always get the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: [ERB] CRASH: main in de.jzbor.epos.debug(11450)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: de.jzbor.epos.debug, PID: 11450
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.jzbor.epos.debug/de.jzbor.epos.activities.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable de.jzbor.epos.debug:drawable/background_splash with resource ID #0x7f07005c
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2891)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1658)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6735)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable de.jzbor.epos.debug:drawable/background_splash with resource ID #0x7f07005c
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_splash.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07005c
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:910)
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:680)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:992)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:928)
                  at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
                  at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:87)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
                  at de.jzbor.epos.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:11)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1658)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6735)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
               Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #8: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
                  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:823)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:754)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1284)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:279)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:897)
                    ... 30 more
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

background_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@color/primaryColor"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</item>
```

It may have something to do with the ".debug" suffix in the build configuration, but I couldn't figure out a solution.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }

}
```

[Edit]
So thanks to your help (especially @kvaruna) I figured out, tha the problem has something to do with the bitmap. Does anybody know if it is possible to use a bitmap there and how to avoid the error?

Comment: **Try changing bkg_splash.xml like  this** 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="315"
                android:startColor="#FF06BEB6"
                android:endColor="#FF0E90D8"
                android:type="linear" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103686/5305430

Comment: Looks like you do not have `background_splash` in default drawable folder .

Comment: @kvaruna Thank you for your help - that solved the problem pretty good. But I am still not ble to use the bitmap - is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: @jzbor It should work with the code you wrote. 

`<item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo_half_white"/>
    </item>` 

Which source folder you are using? To get bitmap.
I would suggest to go with `@drawable` path for bitmap location.